# Disaster - partitions lost, data seemingly alive, how to recover?

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning

***I've used TestDisk*** and it's written my old partition structure of a ~20GiB partition for Vista, ~25GiB partition for 7 (but it now shows up as unallocated) and a ~400GiB partition for documents.

What it's meant to be is a 30GiB partition for 7, some unallocated space, and a ~400GiB partition for documents.

So currently, I have access to all my documents, but not any of the programs I've installed on C:, or AppData, because my boot partition is now supposedly a 20GB vista partition.

I've tried using my Windows 7 install disc's repair function, but that did nothing beyond wasting about 10 minutes of my time.

I'm currently posting from an Ubuntu live CD.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic mode does wonderful things to your train of thought.

After carefully rereading the TestDisk Step-by-Step tutorial, I noted a "Deeper Scan" option, which worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I heard there's a great program for fixing this, it's called TestDisk.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

> TestDisk is a powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help **recover lost partitions** and/or **make non-booting disks bootable again** when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (**such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table**). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Comment: Did you read anything other than the title..?

Comment: Yeah I read the part where you used TestDisk. It's called sarcasm, buddy.